# Framework 7 material layout error

Tags: html, css, html-framework-7

I'm beginner at framework7, i used to work with jquery mobile. 
I tried to create some very simple app with F7 but it has an issue in navbar element align, described in below picture. 
[navbar error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8lRV.png)

So as you can  see L element has class="left" and App has class="center" and R has right class but it doesn't work.

And i know in material design element with class="center" always stick on the left but Why class right doesn't work ???

And as you can see below when i click on menu icon It crashs and moves (every link on navbar not just this)!!!

[icon moves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0mLK.png)

Comment: Please include your images directly in the question, rather than in separate links.

Answer (score 0):

After i searched all the web i found answer, f7 work correctly in android minimum sdk 19 [android 4.4] and crosswalk is required if you want run your app on android minimum 4.0